# ansible with_dict fails when provided with set_fact variable

Tags: dictionary, variables, ansible

I am trying to dynamically provide dictionary name for interface variables.

My ansible task looks like this.

```
- name: Setting interface list
  set_fact:
    one_fact: "{{ host_name }}_interfaces"

- name: deb
  debug: var={{ one_fact }}

- name: Managing Interfaces
  ios_interface:
    enabled: "{{ item['value']['enabled'] }}"
    name: "{{ item['key'] }}"
    state: "{{ item['value']['state'] }}"
  with_dict: "{{ one_fact }}"
```

Dictionary looks something like this

```
---
h1_interfaces:
  Ethernet1/1:
    description: Firewall
    enabled: true
    speed: auto
    state: present
  Ethernet1/2:
    description: asd
    enabled: true
    speed: auto
    state: present
h2_interfaces:
  Ethernet1/1:
    description: Firewall
    enabled: true
    speed: auto
    state: present
  Ethernet1/2:
    description: asd
    enabled: true
    speed: auto
    state: present
```

When i set `with_dict: {{ one_fact }}` i get an error `FAILED! => {"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}`
But when i provide with `with_dict: {{ h1_interfaces }}` it works like a charm. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish... `with_dict` is indeed expecting a dictionary but `one_fact` is initialized to a string. 

Can you elaborate more on what you're expected outcome is?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a variable `host_name` too, which is set to `h1` or `h2`, and you want to access the dictionaries: `h1_interfaces`/`h2_interfaces`.

To construct dynamically the variable name and access its value, you should use the [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-vars-lookup), please see below task:

```
  - name: Setting interface list
    set_fact:
      one_fact: "{{ lookup('vars', myvar + '_interfaces') }}"
    vars:
      myvar: "{{ host_name }}"
```

and a slightly altered playbook to demonstrate the result:

**playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    host_name: h1
    h1_interfaces:
      Ethernet1/1:
        description: Firewall
        enabled: true
        speed: auto
        state: present
      Ethernet1/2:
        description: asd
        enabled: true
        speed: auto
        state: present
    h2_interfaces:
      Ethernet1/1:
        description: Firewall
        enabled: true
        speed: auto
        state: present
      Ethernet1/2:
        description: asd
        enabled: true
        speed: auto
        state: present
    
 
  tasks:

  - name: Setting interface list
    set_fact:
      one_fact: "{{ lookup('vars', myvar + '_interfaces') }}"
    vars:
      myvar: "{{ host_name }}"

  - name: deb
    debug: var=one_fact

  - name: Managing Interfaces
    debug:
      msg: "enabled: {{ item['value']['enabled'] }}, name: {{ item['key'] }}, state: {{ item['value']['state'] }}"
    with_dict: "{{ one_fact }}"
```

**result:**

```
TASK [Managing Interfaces] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'Ethernet1/1', 'value': {'description': 'Firewall', 'enabled': True, 'speed': 'auto', 'state': 'present'}}) => {
    "msg": "enabled: True, name: Ethernet1/1, state: present"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'Ethernet1/2', 'value': {'description': 'asd', 'enabled': True, 'speed': 'auto', 'state': 'present'}}) => {
    "msg": "enabled: True, name: Ethernet1/2, state: present"
}
```

cheers